# ORDER BY number_column DESC: why does a smaller number come before a larger?

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `member` ORDER BY `posts` DESC LIMIT 5
```

I have this little snippet, and it should just sort the list by amount of posts that the user has by that.

For some reason, a user with 4 posts comes before a user with 24 posts. Is it because it only does it according to first digit? How do I fix this?

`posts` is a `varchar` column containing numbers.

I have 7 users in the database for testing, one with 24 posts, one with 21 posts, one with 4 posts, and four with 0 posts. It sorts it 4 > 24 > 21 > 0 > 0.

Comment: Is posts nummeric? Show us the ddl and sample data!

Comment: Is `posts` `INTEGER`?

Comment: Heh, @Jens thanks. I made a stupid mistake and made it as a text in database, just fixed. I kept going over code and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @Jens, can you make that an answer? I'll accept it. Just in case any other noobs have the same problem and Google for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `posts` field is a string.

So, try doing this to sort it as if an integer.

```
 ORDER BY CAST(posts AS INTEGER) DESC
```

that should get the ordering right.

Of course, as @Jens pointed out, you might be smart to fix the column definition instead.

Comment: Thank you. Just a silly mistake on my part, the error wasn't in the code, it was in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Is posts nummeric? If yes cast it to an Integer `CAST(posts AS INTEGER)`

Comment: @TedMobsby I have added my comment as answer. Feel free to upvote or accept it.

Answer (score -2):

Please try this, if your field is of `text` type.

```
SELECT * FROM `member` ORDER BY LENGTH(`posts`) DESC LIMIT 5 // it gives the length in bytes
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `member` ORDER BY LENGTH(`posts`) DESC LIMIT 5 // it count multi-byte characters
```